# Need to get rid of single quotes

Tags: python

```
user_int = int(input('Enter integer (32 - 126):\n'))
user_float = float(input('Enter float:\n'))
user_char = ascii(input('Enter character:\n'))
user_string = str(input('Enter string:\n'))

print(user_int , user_float , user_char , user_string)

print(user_string , user_char , user_float , user_int)
   
print(user_int , 'converted to a character is' , chr(user_int))
```

this is the code I have so far and the only problem I have is that the character is printing with single quotes around it. I can't figure out how to get rid of the quotes.

Comment: why are you casting that to ascii? is that needed?

Comment: post a screenshot of your output.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the line, `user_char = ascii(input('Enter character:\n'))`.

`ascii()` returns a string containing a printable representation of an object and escape the non-ASCII characters in the string. This means the `ascii()` returns what must be fed to the `print()` function to get it to the print the same input given to the `ascii` function. For example,

`ascii('a')` returns `"'a'"` as `print("'a'")` gives `'a'`.

Check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ascii-in-python/) for more details.

Comment: Okay I guess that leaves me unsure what I should be using instead of ascii() then.